# What are unique properties or advantages of tagine?

Tags: cookware

Recently I saw a [tagine from Le Creuset](https://www.lecreuset.at/tagine) and tried to gather more information about it (materials, usage, etc.). But I could not figure how it sets itself apart from Western pots (be it cast iron or other), slow cookers, or terracotta ware like a "Römertopf". All of these can be used to cook food with little to no added liquid and with the use of steam.

What exactly is its advantage over the mentioned alternatives, assuming there is one?

Also, does it really have to be Earthenware, or is cast iron also fine? How does glazing or enamel affects its cooking properties?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  In general, it's much better to ask one question at a time.  Maybe cut off your question at "are there advantages"?  After all, you don't care about ceramic vs. cast iron if there are no advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no intrinsic advantages to using a traditional earthenware Tagine vs. a cast iron one or a dutch oven or a Römertopf or any other regular steel/cast iron or earthenware pot that people use to make stews.

Some/Most say the lid with its shape help the moisture drip down to the base, but so does my flat lid on my pot (or the small dimples on some cast iron lids).

There's a discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskCulinary/comments/34yypn/tagines_any_point_beyond_the_decorative/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cooking/comments/ci654p/is_there_any_practical_use_for_a_tagine_if_you/) about it.

iMO, if wanting to be traditional, use an unglazed earthenware Tagine, and use it often and be careful when using it; but if you cannot find one an use a enamel cast iron one, then there is no difference.